# how to change CropRect when it is loaded?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I found a useful library which works with cropping image in [this link](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor). I want to use it with only one `cropRect` which is `ratio = 3.0f / 4.0f;` instead of choosing them. I added below code in `viewDidApper` method of `PECropViewController`:

```
CGFloat ratio = 3.0f / 4.0f;
CGRect cropRect = self.cropView.cropRect;
CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(cropRect);
cropRect.size = CGSizeMake(width, width * ratio);
self.cropView.cropRect = cropRect;
```

But it is not working.  There is `(void)constrain:(id)sender` method which works when I press `Edit` button. If I write above code in this method it works well. Here is the code:

```
(void)constrain:(id)sender
{
    CGFloat ratio = 3.0f / 4.0f;
    CGRect cropRect = self.cropView.cropRect;
    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(cropRect);
    cropRect.size = CGSizeMake(width, width * ratio);
    self.cropView.cropRect = cropRect;
    return;
{
```

The problem is I can't change `cropRect`'s `ratio` when `croppingView` appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if somebody is looking for solution for this question, i found it. I have just changed `cropAspectRatio` in `PECropView`:

```
- (void)setupImageView
{
    CGRect cropRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(self.image.size, self.insetRect);
    self.scrollView.frame = cropRect;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = cropRect.size;

    self.zoomingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.scrollView.bounds];
    self.zoomingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.zoomingView];

    self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.zoomingView.bounds];
    self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.imageView.image = self.image;
    [self.zoomingView addSubview:self.imageView];

    //i added this line code
    self.cropAspectRatio = 4 / 3.0;
}
```